# AngularJs: Different placeholders based on value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular in one of our project. 
Here is our user table:

```
ID    NAME      WEBSITE    ROLE
1    Nitin     www.n.com    1
2    Abhi      www.a.com    1
3    Vivek     www.v.com    2
4    Mike      www.m.com    0
5    Nav       www.na.com   2

Role: 0 - ADMIN | 1 - ACTIVE MEMBER | 2 - INACTIVE MEMBER
```

Here is my angular view code:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>NAME</th>
                        <th>WEBSITE</th>
                        <th>STATUS</th>
                    </tr>                   
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:query | orderBy:[checkedFunction,dFilter] track by $index ">
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.checked" value="{{ user.ID }}" />
                        </td>
                        <td>{{ user.NAME }}</td>
                        <td>{{ user.WEBSITE }}</td>
                        <td>{{ user.ROLE }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Now my question is how do i show the respective texts for the ROLE? Is there any method where i define the text for the roles and angular uses it to display automatically based on the role?

I can use ng-if statements in the view but i feel its not a great idea.
Does angular has something like

```
{{ user.ROLE ? 0 : 'ADMIN', 1 : 'ACTIVE MEMBER', 2 : 'INACTIVE MEMBER' }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I probably would create a filter for that.

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .filter('role', function() {
    return function (input) {
      var roleTypes = { 0 : 'ADMIN', 1 : 'ACTIVE MEMBER', 2 : 'INACTIVE MEMBER' };
      var role = parseInt(input);
      return roleTypes[role];
    };
});
```

Using:

```
{{user.ROLE | role}}
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09